# How do I use an ORACLE REGEX function to remove all leading and trailing line break characters and spaces?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How do I use an ORACLE REGEX function to remove all leading and trailing line break characters and spaces?

For example, assume I have the following string where  refers to actual invisible carriage return line feed characters. Here's the input:

```
"     
   
   
   SELECT * 
   FROM
   TABLE
              
             "
```

And here's the desire output:

```
"SELECT *
   FROM 
   TABLE"
```

Comment: [`trim()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php)

Comment: That doesn't handle the CRLFs

Comment: `trim()` might require multiple passes so I've provided a `regex_replace()` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it if `regex_replace()` is a requirement:

```
select regexp_replace('     
   
   
   SELECT * 
   FROM
   TABLE
              
             ', '^\s*|\s*$', '') as hello
from dual
```

See https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php for documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A single regexp_replace is sufficient, eg.

```
select regexp_replace(' 
 
 select frut
   from prut
   

','^[[:space:]]*(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*$','\1',1,1,'mn') from dual;
```

results in

```
select frut
   from prut
```